In C# EF Core, how can I concatenate two DbSets
I get an exception when concatenating two DbSets in IQueryable property in the DbContext.
I have tried:
public DbSet<Group> Groups { set; get; }
public DbSet<Chat> Chats { set; get; }
public IQueryable<BaseChat> BaseChats => Chats.Concat<BaseChat>(Groups);

and when I try to get the value of BaseChats I get this exception:

System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable1[Portal.Models.Chat]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable1[Portal.Models.Group]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable1[Portal.Models.Group] Concat[Group](System.Linq.IQueryable1[Portal.Models.Group], System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Portal.Models.Group])' (Parameter 'arg0')

Edit:
BaseChat is an abstract class and Chat and Group inherit from it

Why would you want to do this? Do they derive from the same ancestor? Does it make sense to be able to treat them purely in terms of the common base? Are you thinking of applying any filtering to this operation, or are you going to download two entire tables every time it runs?

Are both collections of the same type?

Check the "Inheritance" documentation for EFCore and implement it properly.

You can't select  ...  union all select ... two different result sets, so I don't see this working. Unless you .Select each query to the same view model.

@flackoverstow yes, both of them derive from the BaseChat abstract class. and I am going to make query on this IQueryable

If I were doing this I'd probably just do the concat client side against projected anonymous types. I don't think it's going to save much of anything to have the DB do it

It should work if you add an explicit projection to your base type for each source DbSet:
public IQueryable<BaseChat> BaseChats => Chats
    .Select(c => new BaseChat
    {
        // map properties here
    })
    .Concat(Groups.Select(g => new BaseChat
    {
        // map properties here
    }));

Note that not all operations will be supported on this IQueryable. Be sure to test these queries properly.
